# Error in datetime module in python script for ni-fi

Tags: apache-nifi

So I am trying to implement this script

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date                                         

flowfile = session.get()
current_date= datetime.today().date()
if flowfile != None:
    src_table_name = flowfile.getAttribute('src_table_name')
    date_filter = str(current_date.replace(day =11))
    if src_table_name in ['Income_project_BP', 'Plan_final_scenario', 'Plan_primary_scenario', 'ProductionCalendar', 'Subcontracting_BP']:  
        flowfile = session.putAttribute(flowfile, 'date_filter', date_filter)
        session.transfer(flowfile, REL_SUCCESS)
    else:
        session.transfer(flowfile, REL_FAILURE)
```

And I've tried a lot of different ways but when it comes to "replace" method I'm always getting this error. Same thing when I am trying to use "strftime" method

[image]

What should I do? I really need this method.

Thank you beforehand!